# How to check whether an object is empty?

Tags: javascript, object, null, undefined

I'm learing JavaScript. I cannot grasp the idea of an empty object. As I understand, there are situations when I need to check a variable whether it holds an object and has a value.

So far, I know that a variable can be **undefined**.

```
var car; // the value is undefined, as well as the type (which is it? number, array, etc.)
```

I also know, that everything that has a value, is **true**:

```
var car = "Opel";
Boolean(car); // true
```

And anything without a value is false:

```
var car = ""; // typeof string, but it is empty, so
Boolean(car); // false
Boolean(null); // false
```

So why doesn't it work the same way with arrays and objects? Why is all of this **true**? Shouldn't empty arrays and objects return **false**?

```
var car = {make: "Opel", year: 2015};
Boolean(car); // true
car = {};
Boolean(car); // true
car = ["BMW", "Opel"]; 
Boolean(car); // true
car = [];
Boolean(car); // true
```

Now I see that there are methods, that can be applied to check an object's length, I just haven't reached that part yet.

**I'm learning at W3Schools website and this bit just got me puzzled:**

But you cannot test if an object is null, because this will throw an error if the object is undefined:

Incorrect:

```
if (myObj === null)
```

To solve this problem, you must test if an object is not null, and not undefined.

But this can still throw an error:

Incorrect:

```
if (myObj !== null && typeof myObj !== "undefined")
```

Because of this, you must test for not undefined before you can test for not null:

Correct:

```
if (typeof myObj !== "undefined" && myObj !== null)
```

**I still cannot understand the last line here.**

Comment: does `Object.entries(car).length > 0` work for you?

Comment: okay, I see this. I just haven't learnt this yet.

Comment: [everything that has a value, is true - And anything without a value is false], actually these are wrong assumptions, 0 is a value, as well as empty string, even boolean false itself is a value, it's not about having value, it's about truthy values and falsy values, read more about how different values are treated when converted to boolean value

Comment: That's a good point. I'm just learning so my choosing of words might have been inaccurate.

Answer (score 50):

Checking if **an object is empty:**

```
Object.keys(yourObject).length
```

Comment: Object.keys(obj)  returns all attribute names

Comment: Perhaps wrap this in a function, for better readability when this is used?

Comment: It's fairer to say that checks if an object is _non-empty_

Answer (score 7):

```
var car = {};
var isEmpty = Object.entries(car).length > 0; //false

var car = {make: "Opel", year: 2015};
var isEmpty = Object.entries(car).length > 0; //true
```

This should solve your problem, if your curious about the utility function Object.entries you can look on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: To ensure that isEmpty does not lead to confusion a better alternative, in my opinion, is: 
`var isEmpty = Object.entries(car).length === 0;`

Comment: Why would you use entries, which also extracts values, instead of just keys?

Answer (score 2):

> I also know, that everything that has a value, is true

I wouldn't say that. All the examples given are *values*, even `undefined` and `null` are predefined values in JavaScript.

> Shouldn't empty arrays and objects return false?

It is like that by specification. And that is really the answer to your question. It is a choice made by the designers of the language.

You could find some logic in it though. In JavaScript, values representing objects (and so also arrays) are *references*. These references are memory addresses/pointers, and although you cannot find out what exactly those addresses are, these are non-zero, even when an object has no properties.

Note that your example objects (`{}` and `[]`) still have some non-enumerable properties, such a `__proto__` and (for array) `length`, so they are not really as empty as you think.

The most empty object you can create, is: `Object.create(null)`

Comment: Then why does an empty string is false?
`var car = "";
car.length`
 still works

Comment: That is because of autoboxing: The string primitive does not have properties, but when you access a property like `length`, then the engine will on-the-fly make a `String` *object* for the primitive (which really is an object, not a primitive), and that *does* have the `length` property.

Comment: So `car.length` is interpreted as `new String(car).length`, and now note that `Boolean(new String(car))` is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check wheather a object is empty or not in this simple way.

```
function objectLength( object ) {
    return Object.keys(object).length;
}

if(objectLength(yourObject) == 0){ 
    //object is empty
}else{
    //object not empty 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Checking if an object is empty:

```js
Reflect.ownKeys(car).length
```

Returns an array with one element when a `Symbol` is used as the key:

```js
let key = Symbol('vin')
let car = { [key]: 'honda' }
Reflect.ownKeys(car).length // => 1
```

Whereas `Object.keys` returns an array with zero elements in this case:

```
let key = Symbol('vin')
let car = { [key]: 'honda' }
Object.keys(car).length // => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

No, they should not be false.

All objects are 'truthy', in that they return true when evaluated as a Boolean. In Javascript, all arrays are objects (try `console.log(typeof [])`), so they also return true, regardless of whether or not they are empty.

To check if any array is empty:

```
if (MYARRAY.length === 0) {
  // console.log(true);
}
```

To check if an object is empty:

```
if (Object.keys(MYOBJECT).length === 0) {
  // console.log(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would always use `typeof myvar !== 'undefined'` and checks for content `myvar !== ''`
This would always would have a clear result.

Answer (score 0):

There are concepts which are Truthy and Falsy values in JavaScript.
I highly recommend you to read MDN documents about this issue.

> All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, -0, 0n, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

[Truthy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

[Falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
  if ($('#element').is(':empty')){
  //do something
  }
```

**OR**

```
function isEmpty( el ){
      return !$.trim(el.html())
  }
  if (isEmpty($('#element'))) {
      // do something
  }
```

Here are some examples: http://api.jquery.com/is/

**But if you need it in JavaScript:**

```
if( typeof foo !== 'undefined' ) {
    // foo could get resolved and it's defined
}
```

**You can simply use typeof**